# What would happen if you used the hair of a metamorphmagus in Polyjuice potion?

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

This is a question I've been thinking about a while now. If a Metamorphmagus doesn't have a set form, and someone takes their hair for a Polyjuice potion, what exactly happens to the person drinking the potion? Do they turn into the form that the magus had at the time, or to the original way that the magus looked before their form started shifting?

Comment: Related: [What would happen if Lupin drank Polyjuice Potion?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47502/21267), [Shapeshifting after death](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63209/21267) and [How do Animagi and Polyjuice Potion mix in Harry Potter?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49347/21267)

Answer (score 7):

Polyjuice clearly copies the **current** appearance of a person - for example, fake Moody copied the injuries, including the missing eye, of a real one. Haircuts are copied as-is (despite hair growing in all wizards as a dynamic thing). Harry's scar was copied in Battle of Seven Potters.

As such, it's more likely that MM's current form when the hair was taken would be copied, since their ability actually change their physical form.

Comment: *… lying on the floor some ten feet below, apparently fast asleep, thin and starved in appearance, was the real Mad-Eye Moody. … chunks of his grizzled hair were missing. … ‘… I kept him alive … I also needed his hair to make the Polyjuice Potion. …’* (GoF, _Veritaserum_) So it seems Crouch Jr. could maintain Moody’s original appearance (and haircut) even when he cut the hair much later. Did he take the potion continuously, even at night (every hour!)?

Comment: @chirlu - that's good evidence! Not conclusive though -  Barty could have magically fixed the thinness and misisng hair after taking Polyjuice.

Comment: Right, that’s a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

### Warning: this contains a lot of 'maybes'

So for this to work, you'd have to take a hair from a metamorphmagus.  This implies that they would **need to be in a form that had hair**.  It is logical to conclude that, assuming it worked at all (remember what happened with Hermione; it's really only designed to work for *people*) it would take the form of whatever the metamorphmagus was in, because the polyjuice potion makes you look like what the hair's owner did.  As the hair is that of something *with* hair, you would probably end up turning to look like that creature or person.

Importantly, bear in mind that *in the movies* when Harry and Ron took the Polyjuice potion, their *voices* didn't change which suggests to me Polyjuice is restricted to **appearance** only!  Yet, as pointed out by Mooz in the comment below, in the *books*, the Polyjuice Potion seems to change one's entire *biology*.  Now I would still argue that it would only change one into whatever form the Metamorphmagus was at the time, because one is taking a hair from whatever form it was in then.  To my mind then, it seems most likely that you would take the form of the being the Metamorphmagus was at the time, rather than assuming the other properties of the Metamorphmagus.

Hence, **assuming the Polyjuice Potion worked at all** (which is doubtful as we've seen with Hermione), one would probably take on the *appearance* of what form the Metamorphmagus was at the time the hair was taken.

Comment: Apparently, voices *do* change when Polyjuiced: [Why is the effect of the polyjuice potion inconsistent?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36560/21267)

Comment: @Mooz That's a really good point actually; I'll modify my answer accordingly!

Comment: It doesn't have to be a hair - 'we need a bit of whoever we're going to turn into (Hermione)'. It's just hairs are eaiest, and apparently nicer than toenails (Ron)